# Receiving duplicate declaration error in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to perform a select statement into a variable that should return `sponsor_id`. However, the following error comes up when executing script:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: duplicate declaration at or near "sponsorid"
```

This is the code:

```
DO $create_study$

DECLARE 
    sponsorid INT; 

sponsorid = (SELECT sponsor.sponsor_id  FROM study.sponsor WHERE SPONSOR_NAME='Novartis');

END $create_study$
```

running the SELECT statement in parenthesis, on its own, yields the correct sponsor_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `BEGIN` block

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=209cc714f7aecdbc1afe2bde005e6415)**

```
DO $create_study$    
DECLARE 
    sponsorid INT; 

BEGIN    
     sponsorid = (SELECT sponsor.sponsor_id  FROM study.sponsor WHERE SPONSOR_NAME='Novartis');

END 
$create_study$
```